# Creating issues with the JIRA API for specific users with assigned permissions to view

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, confluence

I am new to JIRA API automation and would like to know how I could use the JIRA API to create an issue for specific user who have restricted permissions to view - the API to be used is as follows -https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-post

Thanks,

Best Regards,

Nuzhi

I tried going through the API documentation but could not find any particular detailed documentation with regards to the use case.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean you want to create a JIRA issue, that is viewable by a specific user? You can assign people and also make people watch an issue you have created with the python JIRA api library. https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html I dont see many reasons to use REST API instead of the python library

Comment: View restrictions are usually handled with security levels